# What can cause \ref{} of LaTex output a [??]

Tags: latex

I include a figure like this

```
\begin{figure*}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=6.7in]{pic/recall_details.png}
\caption{ Recalls of test query MB002-MB049}
\label{ recall_details}
\end{center}
\end{figure*}
```

And then I refer it using `\ref{recall_details}`. Instead of getting numbers like 1, 2, I get ??. Literally I mean ??. What is wrong with my codes? How to make the references show correctly?

Comment: You might want to post this in [TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should "compile" your latex code twice to get numbers instead of question marks

Comment: Cool, I think I find my problem. Two things, first is I leave some whitespaces in the \label{}, and second is even after correcting them, I need to run compile twice.

Comment: @YitongZhou: you should look into [`latexmk`](http://latex-mk.sourceforge.net/) or the like, so that multiple compilations are done automagically.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you're referencing `\ref{recalls_details}`, but you've defined `\label{ recalls_details}`. That extra space before `recalls_details` is what gets you `??` instead of the figure number. You should either change the `\ref` to `\ref{ recalls_details}` or the `\label` to `\label{recalls_details}`.

On another note, I suggest you add a modifier at the start of the label, such as `fig:` in this case: `\label{fig:recalls_details}`. This is useful when you have different types of labels (e.g. to sections, `sec:`, and to equations, `eqn:`).

The bottom line is to **always use the exact string you give within the `\label{}` in the relevant `\ref{}`**.

Comment: I tried use \label to refer the labels, then I get a blank, not a number. Do you know what is going wrong?

Comment: @YitongZhou: If you define a label for something (i.e. `\label{name}`), you insert a reference to it using `\ref` (i.e. `\ref{name}`).